# ClassCastException on Hashmap to Integer

Tags: java, classcastexception

Does anyone know how to fix this ClassCastException error? I get: 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer?

my problem is that I thought that I was calling the integer at that location, but apparently not? this assignment is due in 2 hours so ANY help is appreciated. Comments should tell whats going on.

```
public class WhyHellothere {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    process(s);
}

public static void process(Scanner s) {
    HashMap hashmapofpricing = new HashMap();
    HashMap hashmapofcount = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i = 0) {
    String itemDescription;
        int count;
        double unitPrice;

        if ((itemDescription = s.next()).equals("end")) {
            break;
        }
        count = s.nextInt();
        Integer quantityValue;

        if (hashmapofcount.get(itemDescription) != null) {

            quantityValue = (Integer) hashmapofcount.get(itemDescription);
        } else {

            quantityValue = new Integer(0);
        }

        hashmapofcount.put(itemDescription, new Integer(new Integer(count).intValue()
                + quantityValue.intValue()));
        unitPrice = s.nextDouble() * count;
        Double costValue; 

        if (hashmapofpricing.get(itemDescription) != null) { 
           costValue = (Double) hashmapofpricing.get(itemDescription);
        } else {
            costValue = new Double(0); 
        }

        hashmapofpricing.put(itemDescription, new Double(new Double(unitPrice).doubleValue()
                + costValue.doubleValue()));
    }
    Object itemdescription[] = hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();
    Object howmanytimestheitemappears[] = hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();
    int countIteration=0;
    Object pricing[] = hashmapofpricing.entrySet().toArray();
    int priceIteration=0;
    Integer runningmaxamount = new Integer(0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < howmanytimestheitemappears.length; i++) {
    int q = (Integer)howmanytimestheitemappears[i];//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this is where the ClassCastException is. No idea why or how to fix.
        if (q > runningmaxamount.intValue()) {runningmaxamount = q;countIteration = i;
        }
    }
    Double maxcost = new Double(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < pricing.length; i++) {
        Double d = (Double) pricing[i];
        if (d.doubleValue() > maxcost.doubleValue()) {
            maxcost = d;
            priceIteration = i;
        }
    }
    String largestCountItem = (String) itemdescription[countIteration];
    String largestCostItem = (String) itemdescription[priceIteration];
    System.out.println("The largest count item with "
            + runningmaxamount.intValue() + " was: " + largestCountItem);
    System.out.println("The largest total cost item at "
            + maxcost.doubleValue() + " was: " + largestCostItem);
}

}
```

Comment: Please do us a favor and remove all the distracting comments from your code. The easier that we can read and understand your code, the easier it will be to help you. Also, do indicate by obvious comment, probably the **only** comment that should be in your code, which line causes your problem.

Comment: your comments make your code unreadable...

Comment: Well, if you look at the documentation, the only common parent between HashMap$Entry and Integer is Object.

Comment: Tell us what line the exception occurs on.  It's there in the exception data in front of you.

Comment: I've removed all the messy comments, only the line with the exception has any comments to it. a series of <<<<< arrows near the bottom.

Comment: OK, I see it.  And the howmanytimestheitemappears array was filled with `hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray()`, so it would be surprising if it did not contain HashMap entries.  What did you expect?

Comment: another question, should 
'Object itemdescription[] = hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();'
be .keySet().toArray(); instead? or does it not matter?

Comment: Write `int q = (Integer)howmanytimestheitemappears[i].getValue();`. And please, read some books about Java Code Style and programming in general.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will be sure to do so. I'm pretty much a newbie who has thrown himself to the proverbial wolves of java programming. A week ago I didn't know what a String was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a problem with your HashMap declaration and initialization:

Its better to give what types you are storing in your hashmap like:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashmapofcount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then you can traverse it easily with this kind of loop:

```
   for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : hashmapofcount.entrySet()) {
        final String description = entry.getKey();
        final Integer value = entry.getValue();
    }
```

*PS:* And you don't need a lot of `boxing` the integer and doubles which makes your code look little terrible. Another thing you are adding two integers and doubles unitPrice and costValue, i think you might want to concatenate them by using `unitPrice+" "+costValue`(?)

Answer (score 0):

```
Object howmanytimestheitemappears[] = hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < howmanytimestheitemappears.length; i++) {
    int q = (Integer)howmanytimestheitemappears[i];/
....
}
```

`howmanytimestheitemappears[i]` is of type HashMap$Entry. To get the key you need to call `howmanytimestheitemappears[i].getKey()`
Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html.

Comment: If i change it to `howmanytimestheitemappears[i].getKey()` or even to `howmanytimestheitemappears[i].getValue()` then it gives me an error saying "the method getKey() is undefined for type Object". How do I fix this? Sorry, I'm a new student at this, but hopefully a quick learner.

Comment: Change `Object howmanytimestheitemappears[]` to `Map.Entry howmanytimestheitemappears[]`

Comment: If I do so, it tells me Map can't be resolved to a type.

Comment: You need to import `java.util.Map` as well.

Comment: I just realized I didn't have it, but even so it further adds that "type mismatch, can't convert from Object[] to Map.Entry" 

Does this mean I can't use `entrySet().toArray();` and that I'll have to do something different?

Comment: `Object itemdescription[] = hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();
  Map.Entry howmanytimestheitemappears[] = (Map.Entry[]) hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();
  


for (int i = 0; i < howmanytimestheitemappears.length; i++) {
   int q = (Integer)howmanytimestheitemappears[i].getKey();`
....

Comment: making that change clears me through the original ClassCastException, but instead I get stuck here:
'Map.Entry howmanytimestheitemappears[] = (Map.Entry[])hashmapofcount.entrySet().toArray();'
It tells me that 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.Map$Entry;"

so we are back to square one.